# Bad characters and sql*loader

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

how to find out mal characters(unsupported eg. Ω ) when inserting using sqlloader? or 
list the mal characters to avoid junk data?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think I understand the question.  Does this: http://www.akadia.com/services/ora_sql_loader_utf8.html provide an answer?

Also, you might look at the Oracle® Database Globalization Support Guide for your version of Oracle: http://www.oracle.com/technology/documentation/index.html.